# How to call a stored procedure and return a value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hey all,
I have a stored procedure and I need to call it within another stored procedure, but I want the first one to return a value (field value).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rnd_STR
(
    @Length int

)

@alphaVar varchar(10) OUTPUT
AS
SET @alphaVar = 'blah'

 #procedure body
END
GO

DECLARE @alphaVar varchar(10)

EXEC rnd_STR @alphaVar output

SELECT @alphaVar
```

**ERRORS**

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure rnd_STR, Line 6

Incorrect syntax near '@alphaVar'.

Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure rnd_STR, Line 8

Must declare the scalar variable "@alphaVar".

Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 4

Could not find stored procedure 'rnd_STR'.

(1 row(s) affected)

didn't work !!

How can I call it??

***BTW, the returned @ID is a string***

Comment: You can't use a scalar-value where a table-value is expected :( (That means using 'select' is over-complicating/causing the issue here.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You say `@alphaVar` is `varchar(10)`. In that case you need to use an output parameter as below. `Return` can only be used for integer types in stored procedures.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rnd_STR
@Length int,
@alphaVar varchar(10) OUTPUT    
AS
BEGIN
SET @alphaVar = 'blah'
/* Rest of procedure body*/
END

GO

DECLARE @alphaVar varchar(10) 

EXEC rnd_STR 10, @alphaVar output

SELECT @alphaVar
```

Alternatively you could use a scalar UDF rather than a stored procedure.

Comment: @alphaVar is varchar(10), what's the output parameter?

Comment: @Martin: should I put the stored procedure body before GO statement?

Comment: @Shaza - Yes. Anything after the `GO` will not be included in the stored procedure definition.

Comment: @Martin: when I've added the following
@alphaVar varchar(10) OUTPUT
AS
SET @alphaVar = 'test'
these errors appeared:
Incorrect syntax near '@alphaVar'.
Must declare the scalar variable "@alphaVar".

Comment: @Shaza - If you update your question with the exact code you are trying to run I'll take a look.

Comment: @Shaza - The output parameter needs to go next to the other parameter. See edit.

Comment: Sorry but didn't see any change, didn't get the idea.

Comment: @Shaza - If you can't see any change in my answer then there's not much else I can do to help you sorry.

Comment: In your answer !! I thought in my question.
yes sure I can see the changes.
thanks a lot everything went just fine :)

Answer (score 11):

You're calling syntax is wrong.

```
 DECLARE @newId int
 EXEC @newId = rnd_STR, @length = 10
```

See [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) in the reference.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'd missed that. Something called @ID in my database would, by convention, always be an int!! Martin's OUTPUT parameters are definitely the way to go in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EXEC @alphaVar = rnd_STR 10
```

Answer (score 0):

A work around  of getting this code is to execute the stored procedure in your `Management Studio` itself and copy the `SQL` code