# Stored Procedure returning a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, return, varchar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ‘Internet Explorer 3 original’ to data type int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571263/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-nvarchar-value-internet-explorer-3-origin)

So I created this following simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 'works!'
END
GO
```

I then wanted to execute it by firing the following statement:

```
EXEC test
```

Why am I getting the following error all the time?

**Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'works!' to data type int.**

Oh and btw, (when) is it necessary to have the GO-statement in the end of a stored procedure? I guess it takes no effect here since it will jump out of the procedure when I am returing my @out String.

Comment: Have a look at [Return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx). You probably want to be doing `Select 'works!'`

Comment: And regarding your quesion about `GO` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio

Answer (score 25):

Using [RETURN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) only allows you to return an INTEGER code

You either need to SELECT the value

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE test
   AS
   BEGIN
       SELECT 'works!'
   END
```

or if you want to assign into a variable in the caller, use an OUTPUT parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @outputVal VARCHAR(20) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @outputVal = 'works!'
END

DECLARE @val VARCHAR(20)
EXECUTE test @val OUTPUT
```

Comment: ooh that's why, hah! thank you very much, now I can go home and enjoy my weekend :-)

Comment: You need to `SELECT @val` at the end of the second procedure to get it to output